# Golang fix jpeg bad EOF formatting

Tags: go, jpeg

For some jpeg image, the EOI is not ending with `\xff\xd9`, my example I see `\xff\x00`, so I am trying to fix this using go.

```
f, _ := os.Open("bad.jpeg")
img, _, err := image.Decode(f)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println("successfully decoded")
opt := jpeg.Options{
    Quality: 100,
}
f1, _ := os.Create("good.jpeg")
jpeg.Encode(f1, img, &opt)
```

however, `image.Decode(f)` failed due to `unexpected EOF`, I would like to know how to fix the ending problem for bad formatted jpeg file.

With Python, I can simply do the following, `open` and `save` will automatically fix the EOI for me, any equivalent way in Go?

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("bad.jpeg")
im.save("good.jpeg", quality=100)
```

here is the [image](https://github.com/xuchen81/xuchen81.github.io/blob/master/img/bad.jpeg) I am testing

Comment: Read the file to a buffer, attempt to decode it. If it fails with that error, add the missing bytes and try to decode it again.

Comment: could you please upload the broken image ?

Comment: I have attacked the image.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fairly naive solution that only works for this very specific case:
read the file, try to decode it. If it fails to decode, check the last two bytes and overwrite the last one if it's a known pattern. Try to decode it again. If successful, write the fixed bytes to the new file.

```golang
package main

import (
  "bytes"
  "image"
  _ "image/jpeg"
  "io/ioutil"
) 
  
func main() {
  contents, err := ioutil.ReadFile("bad.jpeg")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  
  buffer := bytes.NewBuffer(contents)
  _, _, err = image.Decode(buffer)
  if err == nil {
    return
  }
  
  if err.Error() != "unexpected EOF" {
    panic(err)
  } 
  
  // Maybe wrong End-Of-Image.
  if contents[len(contents)-1] == '\x00' && contents[len(contents)-2] == '\xff' {
    contents[len(contents)-1] = '\xd9'
  } else {
    panic("don't know what to do")
  } 
  
  // Reset buffer and decode again.
  buffer = bytes.NewBuffer(contents)
  _, _, err = image.Decode(buffer)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  
  // Write fixed buffer to the new file.
  err = ioutil.WriteFile("good.jpeg", contents, 0644)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}
```